Как получить доступ к объекту в Heap, не имеющему ссылок?
После окончания использования объекта, он некоторое время продолжает оставаться доступным в памяти и способа избежать этого не существует. Каким образом можно получить ссылку на данный объект, пока его не удалил GC, и можно ли это вообще. Можно ли каким-либо образом обратиться к объекту в Heap, на который нет ссылок из GC root?

Остановите JVM, проинспектируйте память. GC хранит в специальной коллекции все объекты, которые ещё не удалены. Просмотрев эту коллекцию можно отыскать логин и пароль, если автор системы достаточно наивен.

Ответ очень простой - если вам нужен объект, то просто сохраняйте ссылку на него.

Ну а если такая ситуация: злоумышленник пытается заполучить информацию о пользователе. Пароль и логин пользователя сохраняются в виде объектов String, которые, после завершения сессии продолжают существовать в Heap. Каким образом злоумышленник может подступиться к этим личным данным?

Пароль и логин не хранятся в строках. Они хранятся в массивах байт, которые заливаются нулями сразу после использования. В нормально устроеной системе пароль не хранится. Вместо него хранится хеш от пароля, по которому пароль не восстанавливается.

Так вы у нас злоумышленник?
